# How to sort taxonomy view in orchard project?

Tags: sorting, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

This question is related to Orchard Project 1.7.1(http://orchardproject.net/).

Here is my setup. I have my custom content type, Event. I created a custom field for the Event call EventDate (which is of Datetime type). I am able to add taxonomy part to the Event type, after install the Taxonomy module.

Everything works as expected, when I clicked on the taxonomy links, it showed a list of events.

However the event is not sorted based on EventDate. I could not find any documentation to tell me where to define the custom sort order for the custom field I defined for the Event type.

Please note that I am not referring the sort order of the taxonomy (which is defined when I created the projection for the taxonomy). I am referring to the Event list sort order after clicked on the taxonomy link.

Thank you very much in advance!

derek

Comment: You might want to try using Projections in conjunction with Taxonomies, in order to customize everything beyond the basic parameters that Taxonomies offer.

Answer (score 1):

I read the code, and found out that it is sort descending on creation date/time. So I enabled the allow modify creation date/time in the content definition page. It is not idea, but it works.